# Turning a schematic into a map with directions...

Tags: jquery, dictionary, imagemap

I have an image of a schematic... 
[image]

Basically, the idea here is to map out all the cubicles in this office. Then, based on the input of cubicle-A to cubicle-B... the layout would then add a directional line from A to B, showing where the employee has to go.

This seems like a very useful tool in a larger office building...

I've seen lots of jquery map plugins out there...

Is there a plugin already out there that does this?